# Factorial using Task

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to use task to compute factorial of a number. My purpose is to compare the result with factorial using a sequential loop. For example
16! task1 = 16*15*14*13*12*11 and task2 = 10*9*8*7*6 and task3 = 5*4*3*2*1
I have searched online but I cannot find a solution that matched my need. Thanks in anticipation.

```
static long factorialmethod(int number)
         {
            long factorial;
            factorial = number;
            if (number <= 1) { return 1; }
            else
            for (int i = number-1; i >= number; i--)
            {
                factorial *= i;
            }
        return factorial;
           }
      static void Main(string[] args)
         {
        int number;
        Console.WriteLine("Please input your whole number");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("\nFactorial of the number is {0}",factorialmethod(number));
        Console.ReadKey()
         }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use tasks? As your example shows, you might start at the basics.I advise you to read this: [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) Then you know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easiest way to try parallel when computing factorial is *PLinq* (*Parallel* Linq):

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    static long factorialmethod(int number) {
      if (number <= 1)
        return 1; // strictly speaking, factorial on negative (-N)! = infinity

      return Enumerable
       .Range(1, number)
       .AsParallel() // comment it out if you want sequential version
       .Aggregate(1L, (s, a) => s * a);
    }
```

Use `Stopwatch` to benchmark; comment out `.AsParallel()`: do you really want parallel implementation (let `Task` alone)?

Comment: Yes. I want parallel implementation. partitioning any given number into three segments and running them in parallel. I want to compare the result with the normal factorial computation as shown in the code above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DmitryBychenko answer if you want to go PLINQ way. But as an alternative, you can directly use the Parallel library too. If you are literally trying to solve your stated problem using Task library, I think PLINQ is a cleaner solution, but if you are using the posted question as a reduced version of some similar problem, where you need more control, then the below solution might help

```
static long Factorial(int number) {
    if (number < 1)
        return 1;

    var results = new ConcurrentBag<long>();
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(1, number + 1, 5 /*You can select your range size here. You can also derive it based on Environment.ProcessorCount, if you so wish */),
        (range, loopState) => {
            long product = 1;
            for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++) {
                product *= i;
            }
            results.Add(product);
        });

    long factorial = 1;
    foreach (var item in results)
        factorial *= item;
    return factorial;
}
```